# React useNavigate doesn't work properly, need explanation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want to search for posts using the search bar in the navbar and navigate to the searched posts page. But after clicking the button or pressing enter an error occurs. Let's say I want to search for the word music. My URL is supposed to be `'/search?q=music'` but shortly after it becomes `'/search?search=music'` and shows me the Page does not exist page because the query becomes null. If I use `e.preventDefault` before navigating the code works. But I don't know what causes the URL to change so I need an explanation. Also, another issue is that on the search page, the `console.log` shows an empty posts array even after doing the dispatch operation.

navbar component

```
export const Navbar = () => {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleSearch = (e) => {
    navigate(`/search?q=${search}`);
  }

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className='navbar'>
        <h1><Link className='navLink' style={{textDecoration: 'none'}} to='/blog'>BLOG</Link></h1>
            <form onSubmit={(e)=> handleSearch(e)}>
            <input type='text' placeholder='Search' name='search' value={search} onChange={(e)=> {setSearch(e.target.value)}}/>
            
            <input type='submit' value='Go' />
            </form>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link className='navLink' style={{textDecoration: 'none'}} to='/login'>Login</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link className='navLink'  style={{textDecoration: 'none'}} to='/register'>Register</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  )
}
```

The search results page

```
export const SearchedPosts = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const posts = useSelector((state)=> state.newReducer.posts);
  const query = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const key= query.get('q');
    
  useEffect(() => {
    const get = () => {
      dispatch(getPosts(key));
    };
    get();
    setLoading(false); 
    console.log(posts);    
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <div>LOADING...</div>
    )
  }
     
  console.log(key);
  if (key==='' || key===null) {
    return (
      <div>PAGE DOES NOT EXIST</div>
    )
  } else {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        {posts.length > 0 ? (
          <div className='postContainer'>        
            {posts.map((post) => (  
              <div className='postitem' id='postitem' key={post.id}>
                <h2 id='postid'>{post.title}</h2>
                {post.text}
              </div>
            ))} 
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div>No results found</div>
        )}
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

app.js

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Login />} />
          <Route path='/login' element={<Login />} />
          <Route path='/register' element={<Register />} />
          <Route path='/search' element={<SearchedPosts />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  )
}
export default App
```

Comment: When you post the form you are passing in a field name of `search`. Change your input name to `q`. GET forms post the filled out values as query variables (i.e. in the URL)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did some research and found the same answer. It's caused by the default behavior of form submission. I didn't know much about this. But using preventDefault before navigating would be better right? Because if i change the input name to q the page refreshes and the app gets re mounted.